# How to pass json to post request with jsp?

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, post

I have problem with sending params to post method. Maybe, I'm sending the input parameters wrong there, beacause this request get **400 error**

My strcuter of method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
  public @ResponseBody
  String createProject(@RequestBody TestClass project) {
  return "success";
  }
```

Object:

```
public class TestClass {

  private String name;
  private int age;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
Successful create project
</body>
</html>
```

And this i send from postman, but  400 error:
[image of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGxTd.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/HeadersRequestCondition.html),

> Expressions passed to the constructor with header names 'Accept' or
>   'Content-Type' are ignored.

Can you try with `produces` and `consumes` attributes for Accept and Content-Type?